# How to load multiple Excel files in multiple folders into SAS and append into one final table?

Tags: sas

I am a SAS developer.

Currently i have a scenario where there are many excel files in many subfolders in Linux server. The directory is :

```
/sasdata/source/tttt/pppp_List_Files/Centre/ABBA/
/sasdata/source/tttt/pppp_List_Files/Centre/LPPL/
/sasdata/source/tttt/pppp_List_Files/Centre/XXXX/
and many more
```

There are also excel files in :

```
/sasdata/source/tttt/pppp_List_Files/Corner/
/sasdata/source/tttt/pppp_List_Files/Top/
/sasdata/source/tttt/pppp_List_Files/Bottom/
/sasdata/source/tttt/pppp_List_Files/Store/
```

I tried using some sample code that i found online as below:

```
%*Creates a list of all files in the DIR directory with the specified
extension (EXT); 

%macro list_files(dir,ext);
%local filrf rc did memcnt name i;
%let rc=%sysfunc(filename(filrf,&dir));
%let did=%sysfunc(dopen(&filrf));

%if &did eq 0 %then %do;
  %put Directory &dir cannot be open or does not exist;
  %return;
%end;

    %do i = 1 %to %sysfunc(dnum(&did));         
        %let name=%qsysfunc(dread(&did,&i));

        %if %qupcase(%qscan(&name,-1,.)) = %upcase(&ext) %then %do;
                %put &dir\&name;
                %let file_name =  %qscan(&name,1,.);
                %put &file_name;

                data _tmp;
                    length dir $512 name $100;
                    dir=symget("dir");
                    name=symget("name");
                    path = catx('/',dir,name);
                    the_name = substr(name,1,find(name,'.')-1);
                run;

                proc append base=list data=_tmp force;
                run;

                quit;

                proc sql;
                    drop table _tmp;
                quit;

            %end;       
            %else %if %qscan(&name,2,.) = %then %do;
                %list_files(&dir/&name,&ext)
            %end;
    %end;

    %let rc=%sysfunc(dclose(&did)); 
    %let rc=%sysfunc(filename(filrf));
%mend list_files;

%*Macro to import a single file, using the path, filename and an
output dataset name must be specified; 

%macro import_file(path,
file_name, dataset_name );

    proc import 
        datafile="&source./tttt/pppp_List_Files/Centre/ABBA/&file_name."
        dbms=xlsx       out=&dataset_name replace;  run;

%mend;

*Create the list of files, in this case all XLSX files; 
%list_files(&source./tttt/pppp_List_Files/Centre/ABBA/, xlsx);

%*Call macro once for each
entry in the list table created from the %list_files() macro;
data _null_;
  set list;
  string = catt('%import_file(', dir, ', ',  name,', ', catt('test', put(_n_, z2.)), ');');
  call execute (string);
run;
```

However, it throws error of directory or path not found but im 100% certain that the path exists as i am accessing it now.

Seeking for your help on how to achieve that.

Comment: What throws the error, the call to %listfiles or the call to %import_file.  Which statement is generating the error? (show the log with the error) Does it work if you just write a call to %import_file? In your data null step, you could have leading blanks in NAME or DIR, I would suggest change CATT to CATS.

Comment: You might also consider assigning a single library with multiple paths using the `xlsx` libname engine, but you might run into problems if you have multiple excel files with the same name in different folders. In that case you would need to loop through your folders.

Comment: That's my code...you do need to include the error or where it's being generated at least. I think I used it last week and it worked fine for me. Is SAS running on a server and local, and I'm assuming that's the same place you're looking at?